# Header encoding after export email to EML format (RFC822)

Tags: outlook-redemption, eml, rfc822

We are using Redemption (v5.26) to convert messages from .msg format to .eml format in an Outlook COM addin.

I have created an email with the following subject: **ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP** and copied the subject to the message body. I've sent the message and after I received the message I made my test to check one of out customers report.

Our code does the following:

- saves the current email to a .msg file using the following method _mailItem is the Outlook native [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia):

```
_mailItem.SaveAs(filename, OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

- converts the .msg file to .eml using Redemption (the objects are released of course)

```
rdoSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
rdoMail = rdoSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(input);
rdoMail.SaveAs(output, rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822_Redemption);
```

Then checked the generated file and this is what it represented:
the subject encoded like below:

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-2?B?wVJWzVpUVVJPIFTcS9ZSRtpS00fJUA==?=
```

which is **ÁRVÍZTURO TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP** encoded.

The message body is encoded like below:

```
--7A24CA1FB85D3A4CB677EFC32587A338-474D54B8_message_boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Description: Message text

wVJWzVpU21LVIFTcS9ZSRtpS00fJUA0K
--7A24CA1FB85D3A4CB677EFC32587A338-474D54B8_message_boundary
```

which is encoded correctly.

Our customer reported it the same behavior but in the To and From headers.

Can I do anything to fix these fields encoding or is this a bug?

Comment: Was that a Unicode (olMsgUnicode) or an ANSI (olMsg) MSG file?

Comment: It was olMsg. I tried with olMsgUnicode and it fixed the encoding issue. Thank you Dmitry.